# RegEx C# get the number, the string, the boolean and the punctutation mark (comma)

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to get the three types of variavles, and comma. using this RegEx

```
"(\"(?:\"\"|[^\"])*\"|(?:true|false)*(?:\\d+)*(?:[,])*)"
```

The text pattern is something like this:

*"Felis Catus", true, false, 18*

*"Pig "eggos" domesticus", , false, 6*

*"Gallus domesticus", false, true, 5*

The string and number is doing well, but i can't get the comma separated from bool values, i get mathces like this:

"Felis Catus"

,

**true,**

**false,**

18

Comma must be separated from, in my example (true and false)
The output must be:

"Felis Catus"

,

**true**

,

**false**

,

18

Comment: It would help if you could include your expected output. What matches do you want as results?

Comment: "Felis Catus"

,

true

,

false

,

18

The comma must be separated, as match...

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Forget regex, just do a `String.Split`...

```
string s = "\"Felis Catus\", true, false, 18";
string[] parts = s.Split(',');

string text = parts[0];//"Felis Catus"
bool b1 = parts[1].Trim() == "true";//true
bool b2 = parts[2].Trim() == "true";//false
int number = int.Parse(parts[3]);//18
```

Comment: It's only a small part of task, and i already done it, so there is only this small problem. To rewrite it back to String.Split is not the option.
But thank you.

Comment: @RazieLakaALieN: so expand my code example to include the extra values. RegEx is not an ideal solution for parsing. It is best saved for string input validation, in my opinion (and maybe complex searching too)

Comment: Made it by searchign not the comma, but the space, after comma.
The full code is [here](http://ideone.com/IXfS7G)